# jsPDF library does not work in Lightning components 43.0 version

Tags: lightning-aura-components, locker-service, libraries

I have stored jsPDF library in static resource and using it in lightning component where version is 43.0. This library does not work if LockerService is enabled.I decreased version to 39.0 and then it was working properly.

What are the workarounds to solve this issue without changing 43.0 Version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only way to resolve this issue is to edit `jsPDF` library file itself, which will be a great pain. So, I decided to go old school and created a `VF page` which renders `PDF` and is called upon when user clicks a button on lightning component.